# When do browsers render spaces in inline elements?

Tags: html, css

```css
span {
    font-size: 300%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>   aa   </span><span>bb</span><span>   cc   </span><span>   dd   </span><span>   ee   </span>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, spaces are displayed only after "aa" and "dd", and around "cc". Why aren't any spaces displayed before "aa" and "dd" or around "ee"? Is this documented in any specification?

Comment: The HTML 4.01 spec had a bit to say about this here, https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html Not sure where to find any equivalent in the HTML5 spec right now though.

Comment: @CBroe: This is now covered in the CSS spec.

Comment: It's not empty, it's a space! You just have text with spans in it. White space _is_ rendered in general, but multiple spaces by default are collapsed into a single space, and white space at the beginning and end of a text flow (say, a paragraph) is trimmed. In your picture, the browser has done that from left to right, causing the white space at the start of `dd` being trimmed because there is already a space after `cc`. So this space collapsing that you see totally makes sense, but I don't know if there is a formal standard that says which of the spaces between `cc` and `dd` should be kept.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [section 16.6.1 of the CSS2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#white-space-model). There's a lot of words there, but the important bit is here:

> any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed.

This means that whitespace collapsing does not take opening or closing tags into account:

1. In `<span>   cc   </span><span>   dd   </span>`, the space before "dd" is removed (collapsed), leaving just the space after "cc".
2. In `<span>   dd   </span><span>   ee   </span>`, the space before "ee" is removed, leaving just the space after "dd".

Since there are no spaces in the element containing "bb", the spaces after "aa" and before "cc" are unaffected.

The following steps apply to the start and end of the line:

> As each line is laid out,
>
> 1. If a space (U+0020) at the beginning of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is removed.

This is why the space before "aa" is removed.

> 3. If a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is also removed.

This is why the space after "ee" is removed.

Comment: thanks,at first I thought they were **inter-element white space** from https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models

Comment: @Tim: It's not inter-element whitespace because the whitespace forms part of the same text node as the letter it's surrounding. So for example the span containing "cc" contains just one text node with the letters *and* the spaces.